Kernel Mode Driver, Empty (KMDF) No Linker under Configuration Properties
The problem: There is no Linker, Driver Settings, Driver Install ,Inf2Cat and so on... under Configuration Properties.
I have installed Visual Studio 2022 with the following components:

Desktop development with C++
Windows SDK 10.0.26100.1
WDK 10.0.26100.1
Windows 10
Visual Studio Version 17.10.4

I also executed:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Vsix\VS2022\10.0.26100.0\amd64\WDK.vsix
Now I am trying to create a simple driver (KMDF). I used the following templates (neither is recognized):

Kernel Mode Driver, Empty (KMDF)
Kernel Mode Driver (KMDF)

After I create the project, I go to Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->General. The Configuration Type shows Driver, but there is no Linker or other driver-specific options like Driver Settings, Driver Install, Inf2Cat, etc.
Here are the steps I have taken:

Reinstalled Visual Studio, SDK, and WDK.
Moved the same project to a VM where the driver are recognized and Configuration Properties is set properly.

There is no Linker, Driver Settings, Driver Install ,Inf2Cat and so on... under Configuration Properties.

Any guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

After my test, I did not encounter the same situation as yours:

Please make sure you have configured Windows SDK and WDK in the correct way.
To install Windows SDK, please download and install it from the following link:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/
To install and configure WDK in VS, follow the tutorials in the following official documents:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install-the-wdk-using-nuget#install-the-latest-wdk-using-nuget---step-by-step

Installing WDK from NuGet packages solved the problem.

Just install latest version of Windows SDK. It's not installed as default.

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
